# Headless Temperature Controller W/ Web Interface?

Tags: headless, gui, temperature

I am trying to get started on my first project, and I am already overwhelmed. I will be using the Pi headless as a hot tub controller. I know basic Python, and was hoping to use that to control the GPIO pins. I would like to add more features later, but to start off, the Pi will be connected to a temperature sensor in the water, and the heater/pump will be connected to a relay connected to the Pi. I was planning to use Python to store the temperature setpoint in a variable, and write some logic to cycle on/off the heater to maintain a temperature close to the set point. But I also would like to remotely change the set point via a GUI. A web page interface would be good.

Should I use WebIOPi or something else? Would the logic be programmed directly with that somehow? Or just a python script with a library for some kind of interface to add on? What should I turn to now?

Comment: This question is too broad and open ended.  Can you break it down into smaller questions, ideally with some effort shown toward answering those smaller questions? We can't build a software architecture for you like this.